# Facebook Open Graph seems buggy via app share dialog

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When I share a link on Facebook, if i'm sharing from web, everything is perfect, title, description and images are alright.

But when I try to share a link from an app (iOS) there is no thumbnail.

Example link: 
http://www.bilemezsin.com/whatsapp-in-pip-ozelligi-tum-kullanicilara-acilir--28426?refli=8053

Open Graph Debugger Result: 
[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/lWPRQb.png]

Web Share Result on Facebook
[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/Ak8PG0.png]

App Share Result on Facebook
[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/OL8OaZ.png]

I tried with other apps, too, via their Facebook share buttons on my iOS 10, iPhone 7.

I can't see what I'm missing, is it a Facebook bug?

- I have tried to change SEF links to actual links but nothing changed.
- I have tried clearing cache from Open Graph debugger, again, nothing.
- I have tried many other apps, but they all seem failing when sharing
  is initialized from mobile app. Sharing the same URL from the solves
  the missing image problem.

**Can you** try to share any content from any app to Facebook and tell me the result? It'll be appreciated.

Note: everything was working fine till today.

Thank you.

Comment: having the same problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a Facebook bug. It seems it just started.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1948522638736698/